# Exporting information from MYSQL to Checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I am having issues getting information out of mysql into multiple checkboxes.

The query im using is this.

```
    <?php

$usergroupid = $_SESSION['UserGroupID'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM sites WHERE UserGroupID='{$usergroupid}' ORDER BY sites.Description"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

$description=$row["sites.Description"];
{
?>  
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $description; ?>">
<?php
}

?>
```

but this only inputs 1 checkbox and has no text after it when there are multiple rows in the table.

Comment: `$description=$row["sites.Description"];` should be inside the `while()` brackets `{}`, and it should probably be just `$description=$row["Description"];`

Comment: Code always does what has been written to it. If you wonder why it does different than you thought, think a moment: Re-reading must uncover the issue. So understand what the code does by re-reading it again letter by letter. Benefit from the fact that your expectation was not matched and turn it into a learning experience. Asking here just because of having an issue will rob you your self-experience (and is also not really a programming question). So better think twice if something does not work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for starters, never use the same id twice in HTML (you go through a for loop and make each element have the same id, not a good thing). Fix that issue first (make the HTML input element's id include some kind of id from the row)

Then, the real problem comes from the fact that you put the

```
$description=$row["sites.Description"];
```

line before your opening brace for the while statement. It should be

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
$description=$row["sites.Description"];
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code to:

```
<?php

$usergroupid = $_SESSION['UserGroupID'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM sites WHERE UserGroupID='{$usergroupid}' ORDER BY sites.Description"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$description=$row["sites.Description"];

?>  
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $description; ?>">
<?php
}

?>
```

The problem was that the "{" should've been written directly after "while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))".

Also, I would strongly recommend stop using mysql_query if possible, since mysql_query is now deprecated (read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysqli extension instead mysql(is deprecated)

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM sites WHERE UserGroupID='{$usergroupid}' ORDER BY sites.Description"; 
$i=0;
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $description=$row["sites.Description"]; 
    $xxx= "<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox_$i' value='$description'>";
 $i++;
}
 echo $xxx;
?>
```

$description have to be inside the while.

id="checkbox_$i Add autoincrement to make diferent the ids

Comment: If you are going to provide a `mysqli_*` suggestion, (1) make sure you provide accurate examples, ie. [`mysqli_query()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) requires the connection link as the first parameter - `mysqli_query($link,$sql)`, and (2) if updating to `mysqli_*`, make sure to highlight the main advantage of `mysqli` which is prepared statement, so they are not open to SQL Injection - `WHERE UserGroupID='{$usergroupid}'`

Answer (score 0):

It's not the only issue your code has. For example the formatting, I mean you can't really read it. Learn to properly format your code, sort it up. That will actually help you to prevent other errors.

And as commented, it will also help you to read and understand your code.

And now as the third tip: If you ask a question with properly formatted code you will also get better answers here on the website. So please keep your issues important and do all the best you can do to get help here on site.

```
<?php

$usergroupid = $_SESSION['UserGroupID'];

$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE UserGroupID = %d ORDER BY sites.Description",
    (int)$usergroupid
);

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $description = $row["sites.Description"];

    echo '<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="',
         $description, '">';
}
```